# Where do I place code allowing for more lines on UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5.1

I want to add a second line to my UILabel but I have no idea where to put the code and I am stuck without it.
    #import

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UITextField *TramNumber;
IBOutlet UILabel *Tramresult;



}
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)DismissKeyboard;



@end
```

This is the code in my ViewController.h, Tramresult is my UILabel.

Comment: A small comment, properties and methods should not start with a capital letter. Second you want to set the `numberOfLines` of your [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/index.html) to 2 for to lines or 0 for unlimited lines.

Comment: And the setting of this can occur in the XIB -- it doesn't have to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in Interface builder (probably best for you), or in any place of code. In that case the best place will be ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [Tramresult setNumberOfLines:0];  
}
```

Comment: So I did put it in the right place, just tested the wrong thing

Comment: I do not understand now. Is it working for you?